# Pandas Create DataFrame of Multiple Column Counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
From         To
--------------------
DC           Boston
DC           Boston
Boston       DC
Atlanta      LA
LA           Atlanta
```

I want to create a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
City       From      To
-----------------------
DC         2         1
Boston     1         2
Atlanta    1         1
LA         1         1
```

Each row contains the number of times in which the city is in the 'From' and the 'To' columns.

What is the cleanest way to create such a DataFrame in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `value_counts`:

```
# use df[['From','To']].apply(...) if you have other columns
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
```

Output:

```
         From  To
Atlanta     1   1
Boston      1   2
DC          2   1
LA          1   1
```

---

**Update**: Another option, which is slightly faster:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(0)
```

Tested:

```
%timeit -n 100 (df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()))
# 3.7 ms ± 71.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n 100 df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(0)
# 2.98 ms ± 87.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```